# How to limit program runtime, memory usage and as a specific user programmatically in Linux

Tags: c, ruby, cpu-usage, memory-limit, least-privilege

Is there a programmatically way to limit duration, memory usage and run as less privileged user of a Linux program execution in C/C++ or Ruby ?

since system or `` can't do this.

```
sprintf(cmd_str,"/tmp/pro-%d < /tmp/in.txt > /tmp-%d.txt",id,id);
system(cmd_str); // in C

`/tmp/pro-#{id} < /tmp/in.txt > /tmp/out-#{id}.txt` // in Ruby
```

both statement makes that command run as the same user as the executor, uses whole processing power and memory as they like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `setrlimit` syscall to limit memory (`Process::RLIMIT_AS`).  To limit the runtime of the program, you can only control the total number of seconds a process gets CPU time (so that doesn't account for time spent sleeping or waiting on I/O).  That's done with `Process::CPU`.

Drop privileges with `Process::Sys.setgid` followed by `Process::Sys.setuid` *after* setting these rlimits, but before calling your target process with `Process::exec`.

Example target program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#define ALLOC_SIZE_1  1024
#define ALLOC_SIZE_2  (1024 * 1024 * 5)

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *buf;

  fprintf(stderr, "[+] uid: %d, gid: %d\n", getuid(), getgid());

  fprintf(stderr, "[+] trying to allocate %d bytes (should succeed)...\n", ALLOC_SIZE_1);
  if (NULL == (buf = malloc(ALLOC_SIZE_1))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] failed!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "[+] success.\n");
  free(buf);

  fprintf(stderr, "[+] trying to allocate %d bytes (should fail)...\n", ALLOC_SIZE_2);
  if (NULL != (buf = malloc(ALLOC_SIZE_2))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] succeeded!  (should have failed.)\n");
    return -1;
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "[+] ok.  now doing infinite loop (should get killed pretty soon)...\n");
  for (;;);

  return 0;
}
```

And accompanying Ruby script to invoke it (run this script as root with, e.g. `sudo /tmp/foo.rb`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

TARGET_GID = 99
TARGET_UID = 99

Process::setrlimit(Process::RLIMIT_AS, 1024 * 1024 * 5)
Process::setrlimit(Process::RLIMIT_CPU, 3)

Process::Sys.setgid(TARGET_GID)
Process::Sys.setuid(TARGET_UID)

Process::exec('/tmp/test')
```

And finally, output of running on my machine:

```
$ sudo ./run.rb
[+] uid: 99, gid: 99
[+] trying to allocate 1024 bytes (should succeed)...
[+] success.
[+] trying to allocate 5242880 bytes (should fail)...
[+] ok.  now doing infinite loop (should get killed pretty soon)...
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `seteuid(2)` system call; sets the effective user ID of the calling process.

Following is Ruby example (See [`Process::Sys.seteuid`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Process/Sys.html#method-c-seteuid))

```
Process.uid    # => 0
Process.euid   # => 0
Process::Sys.seteuid(1000)  # Etc::getpwnam('falsetru').uid == 1000
Process.uid    # => 0
Process.euid   # => 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

As @falsetru noted, the system call you want to run as another user is `setrlimit` or from the command line `su` or `sudo`.

If you want to limit resources, you want to use the `setrlimit` system call or `ulimit` from the shell. That will limit memory usages etc., but not total run duration - you'll have to keep track of the process and `kill` it if you want that.

You might also look at `nice` to set its priority.